# set direction_left on slideholder in android

Tags: android, menu, right-to-left, direction

I am facing to a new challenge with the SlideHolder menu on android , I use this sample code and it is working well , but I want open this menu right to left the screen , how can I set this property?

```
<com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                            android:id="@+id/slideHolder"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            tools:context=".MainActivity"
                            tools:ignore="UselessLeaf,HardcodedText">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this in your xml. Where **tools:openDrawer="end"** is the main key

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="end">
```

**EDIT**

You can use **setDirection** method for this. Which will accept DIRECTION_RIGHT as argument.

Comment: the library you are using is providing a method name **setDirection**. Use that method for the direction

Comment: This will accept **DIRECTION_RIGHT** i think as argument

Comment: @SaeedParand have you got what you need?

Comment: If it helps, then consider it accepting as answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**SlideHolder** also supports revers swipe (from right to left). To enable this feature use:

**setDirection()**

```
setDirection(SlideHolder.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
setDirection(SlideHolder.DIRECTION_LEFT);
```

**NOTE :** This library is deprecated and won't be supported any longer. Instead, I would suggest you to use [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) which is supported by Google and follows their design guidelines.